# Extjs4 form item is lost after submit

Tags: forms, extjs

I have grid in Extjs4 in which I created filefield item.
In my controller I am creating a new form and taking filefield from the grid and giving it to new form as item. After submitting the form I see that filefield is removed from its place, where has it gone?

Here is my code to submit the form:

```
                var me = this;

                var fileform = Ext.create("Ext.form.Panel", {
                    items: [{
                        xtype: filefield
                    }]
                });

                if(fileform.getForm().isValid()){
                    fileform.getForm().submit({
                        url: Server.getUrl("test", "upload"),
                        success: ...

                        failure:  ...
                    });
                }
                else
                    Message
```

Comment: Where is the form ? Do you display it ? My first idea is that the field has been move to the form.

Comment: var fileform is the form. Yes. I also think it is moved to form. How can I prevent it from being moved or can I add it back?

Comment: Why wouldn't you create the filefield directly in a form ? This would simplify, wouldn't it ?